# How to display the src content strictly within iframe only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my application, I am using iframe to display content dynamically within a page, from another domain.

The iframe src can also return a script sometimes. Issue is, in that script sometimes I am having the following part of code:

```
window.top.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(data_to_be_appended);
```

As a result, some of the images are being appended to the parent body tag and overlayed on the actual output and disturbing the application view. I am having a couple of iframes displaying within the same page and having issue with displaying of application view due to this overlay.

Can anyone please let me know that, how I can overcome this overlay issue and display the src related content only within the iframe strictly.